# Environment texture only shows when in camera view

Tags: 3d-view

When I'm the camera view mode, the environment texture shows up correctly, see: [image: Camera view]

However, when I'm controlling the viewport freely, the environment texture doesn't work at all but gets replaced by a random color: [image: free view]

I remember it used to not work this way, but I don't remember what I'm doing differently from before. The background settings I'm using are visible on the right of the picture. I'm also using Filmic blender.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The texture is visible in perspective views only (in ortho you just have a 'global color' like in your second image here)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem actually! If you want to upgrade your comment into and answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Echows, thanks but the comment is clear enough, I think, and this is a duplicated question